# Having trouble installing ROS Jade

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the instructions to install ROS Jade on Ubuntu. I'm able to do all the steps until "Set up your keys". For some reason, when I enter `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 0xB01FA116` on the command line, it works on and off. One minute it will be successful, the next time it'll say that it was unsuccessful and couldn't find the key. Since it worked sometime, I tried to move on to the second step `sudo apt-get update` and I get this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221332/having-trouble-installing-ros-jade/) by [klampotang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25148/klampotang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As per the instructions on the [Jade installation page](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu):

> ROS Jade ONLY supports Trusty (14.04),
> Utopic (14.10) and Vivid (15.04) for
> debian packages.

ROS Jade isn't supported on 15.10; you should [install from source](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Source) or use a different version of Ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0